# Read binary numbers from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a file that contains a list of binary numbers in this format:
0b1111; 0b1010; 0b0101 // 0b1110; 0b0010 and so on. Then, I want to append each section separated by "//" to a list. Each of those sections should be turned into a list that contains all the numbers in the section separated by ";". I finally got the code to work, but after modifying a completely different and unrelated code and reversing the changes, now it breaks. Here is the code I am using currently, as after trying to fix the issue I do not have the original code:

```
programLoad = open("programs.txt", "r")
programLoadList = programLoad.read()
programList = [p for p in programLoadList.split("//")]
programLoad.close()

for index in range(len(programList)):
    programList[index] = [int(n, 2) for n in programList[index].split(";")]
```

I will not put the file here because it is really big. However, all the numbers follow the correct format and when running it fails on the list comprehension with the error "invalid literal for int base 2".

If you need more information to help I will be glad to supply it.

Comment: Source control is a wonderful thing.

Comment: From the error message (which seems to be missing the actual value of n), looks like you probably have two semi-colons in a row, i.e. without an intervening 0bxxxx number in between.

Comment: Does your input file contain new line characters? If that is the case, you will have to split by new line and *'//'*

Comment: Maybe easiest if you stick a `try:... except:...` (with whatever your exception type is) around the final line, and in the except clause print out the value of `programList[index]` to see what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single list comprehension:

```
In [11]: [[int(b, 2) for b in line.split(";")] for line in program_list.split("//")]
Out[11]: [[15, 10, 5], [14, 2]]
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7.8, and this may be the reason for the error i get: Invalid syntax.

Comment: Edit:I got it! It was trying to turn and empty string into a binary number. The string came from the "//" at the end of the text file, which caused it to separate the next line which was empty into its own section. Thanks for teaching me about comprehensions inside each other too! Also, can you have if/else statements in comprehensions like this?       [x*2 for x if x > 2 in [2, 3, 4, 5]]

Comment: @pengowen123 yep, but you do the if at the end, so it's `[x*2 for x in [2, 3, 4, 5] if x > 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Just treat every binary representation as a string and omit first two characters and convert remaining text to integer.

```
programLoad = open("programs.txt", "r")
programLoadList = programLoad.read()
programList = [p for p in programLoadList.split("//")]
programLoad.close()

for index in range(len(programList)):
    print programList[index]
    programList[index] = [int(n[2:], 2) for n in programList[index].split(";")]

print programList
```